# How to filter Future List in Flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, filter, future

I need help with filtering the list.

I populate the list in initState:

```
  Future _organisations;

  Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/organisations.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);

    List<Organization> temp = [];

    for (var item in data) {
      Organization place = Organization(
        address: item['Address'],
        contactInfo: item['Contact info'],
        organization: item['Organization'],
        phoneNumber: item['Phone number'],
        shortDescription: item['Short description'],
        subject: item['Subject'],
        tags: item['Tags'],
      );

      temp.add(place);
    }

    temp.sort((a, b) => a.organization.compareTo(b.organization));

    return temp;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _organisations = readJson();
  }
```

Then I have a button above the list that I want to use to filter the list with setState, however it doesn't work. How can I filter List of type Future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your method `readJson()` has a return value of type `Future<void>` which means you will never be able to get your `List<Organization>` returned.

Moreover you are working with asynchronous operations which means that you will need to use either `await` or `then` to get your value at some points.

Here is an example of how you could fix your code:

```dart
List<Organization> _organisations;

// Simply change the return type to Future<List<Organization>>
Future<List<Organization>> readJson() async {
  final String response =
    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/organisations.json');
  final data = await json.decode(response);

  List<Organization> temp = [];

  for (var item in data) {
    Organization place = Organization(
      address: item['Address'],
      contactInfo: item['Contact info'],
      organization: item['Organization'],
      phoneNumber: item['Phone number'],
      shortDescription: item['Short description'],
      subject: item['Subject'],
      tags: item['Tags'],
    );
    temp.add(place);
  }

  /// Then you need to compare objects that are comparable.
  /// For example if you want to sort your items by their address :
  temp.sort((a, b) =>
    a.address.toLowerCase().compareTo(b.address.toLowerCase())
  );

  return temp;
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  
  /// As you cannot use await in initState you can use then
  /// to perform an action once your asynchronous operation is
  /// done.
  ///
  /// In this case I am assigning the value to _organisations
  /// and causing a rebuild of the interface with setState.
  readJson().then((List<Organization> temp) {
    setState(() => _organisations = temp);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Future<void>` doesn’t return anything. If you want it to return a list it should be `Future<List>`. When you sort the items in the list, what are you comparing them against? Of what type is item[“organisation”]? It needs to be of a comparable type.